# PHP / React / ZeroMQ reverse the publisher subscriber

Tags: php, react-native, zeromq

I have a couple of "subscriber" processes that need to listen from "publishers" - these publishers come and go. The ZeroMQ example code has subscribers connecting to publisher servers. I want the opposite. I want the subscriber to bind to the socket and the publishers to connect.

This is my subscriber;

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

class listener {
    public function gotMessage( $msg ) {
        print("A Message! $msg");
    }
}

$listener = new listener;

$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$subscriber = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_SUB);
$subscriber->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); 
$subscriber->on('message', array( $listener, 'gotMessage'));
$subscriber->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SUBSCRIBE, '');

$loop->run();
```

This is my publisher;

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);

$pub = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUB);
$pub->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
$pub->send("some text");

?>
```

However, the listener does not receive the message.

Is it possible to do it this way round?

Comment: Would you mind to test the same scenario, just **with a `PUSH/PULL` Formal Communication Pattern, to help isolate the root cause of the issue**?

Comment: hi, sry, we ended up coding it ourselves, PHP React now has a socket-client library.